# How to get Simplex-like "robustness" together with bounds in SciPy?

Tags: python, scipy, minimize

I wanted to apply one of the minimizations methods within `sicpy.minimize` to a function which may not always provide smooth derivatives. I've gotten comfortable with the `Nelder-Mead` implementation of the Simplex method, but it does not appear to accept the bounds argument: `(...,bounds=[xmin, xmax],...)`. Reading this [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) it seems only L-BFGS-B, TNC and SLSQP methods accept bounds, and all three of those are based in some way upon Newton's method, and will either calculate a numerical derivative or accept one.

I don't know the exact term, but I'm looking for a 'Simplex-like' or 'derivativeless' method in `scipy` that accepts bounds, but will also be forgiving of functions that will not provide a smooth derivative (one example being staircase-like behavior). For now, I'm doing 1d. Later I may add dimensions, but that's not critical right now.

Comment: I am looking for a minimization method in SciPy that does not use derivatives and allows for bounds. 1d will do for now. *How is this too broad?* Either there is one, or there isn't.

Comment: For 1d, look here http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give **lmfit** a try (http://cars9.uchicago.edu/software/python/lmfit/).

While not part of scipy, but based on, it offers bounded minimization. I use it for curve-fitting and parameters extraction. Nevertheless, I couldn't tell how it would perform on your specific function.

Comment: Hey this is *really interesting*! If I understand correctly, it internally uses the minimization methods in `scipy` (at least sometimes) but provides the user with a much more "pythonic" set of classes to set up the problem. For methods in `scipy` that don't explicitly handle bounds, it [*maps* bounded parameters](http://cars9.uchicago.edu/software/python/lmfit/bounds.html) in user space to `-inf` to `+inf` when exposed to scipy. I could in fact just try to do that myself without `lmfit`! but it looks like fun so I think I'll give it a go. Thank You!!!